# Passing unique_ptr vs raw_ptr?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, unique-ptr, raw-pointer

What is more common in your experience: func1() or funct2()?  Assume func1 and func2 is better not as a Foo class method.

```
void func1(unique_ptr<Bar>& bar) { /* alter pointed to object's attributes */ }

void func2(Bar* const bar) { /* alter pointed to object's attributes */ }

class Foo
{
  unique_ptr<Bar> bar;
  void mutate_bar1(){ func1(bar); }
  void mutate_bar2(){ func2(bar.get()); }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [GotW #91 Solution: Smart Pointer Parameters](http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/):

> **Guideline:** Don’t pass a smart pointer as a function parameter unless you want to use or manipulate the smart pointer itself, such as to share or transfer ownership.
>
> **Guideline:** Prefer passing objects by value, `*`, or `&`, not by smart pointer.

---

> As usual, use a `*` if you need to express null (no widget), otherwise prefer to use a `&`; and if the object is input-only, write `const widget*` or `const widget&`.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with `mutate_bar2()`. You are correctly managing the life-span of your pointer by storing it in a `std::unique_ptr` class member. So you don't need to worry about memory leaks. You can use the raw pointer safely. I don't see any advantage in passing round the `std::unique_ptr` and it is probably slightly slower to access.

Comment: This is assuming, of course, that "altering the attributes" does not involve taking a reference to `bar` for longer than the duration of the function (which is probably a reasonable assumption, in this case).  If it does, you probably shouldn't be using `unique_ptr` in the first place, unless you intend to transfer ownership with `std::move()` or something.

Comment: @Kevin Exactly. If you want the pointer to out-live the object then `std::unique_ptr` is the wrong choice to begin with. That's why I see no advantage passing the `std::unique_ptr`.